# How do I reduce the numbers of lines of the wireframe modifier?

Tags: wireframe

I have a sphere with a wireframe modifier on it.
Is there a setting that allow me to change the numbers of vertical lines created by the wireframe?
I want about 24, on my sphere there must be about ~100 at the very least, and that's not what I'm looking for.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

New solution:

Because my former solution was very "edgy" with low geometry, here a much better shader solution:

[image]

[image]

by changing the scale in the wave textures you can decide how many lines you will see.

blend file: [image]

OLD PROPOSAL:

I would add a new sphere of the same size + position, but with less geometry and give that the wireframe modifier.

Just reduce the segments and rings, because every segment/ring will add lines to your wireframe modifier.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The _Wireframe_ modifier also has the option to limit the wireframe to a vertex group, so you could choose which edges to be affected by it. But this doesn't work well since the wire "fades" towards the vertices not affected... Maybe nice for some special effects, but not in this case...

Comment: this looks awful...i tried it. This is - in my eyes - no solution for this. I agree - for special effects might be a solution.

Comment: I got this: https://imgur.com/a/G9TaHwy 
So now the earth has disappeared, I try to add it as a new material but it doesn't appear. I'm really bad... Can you just provide me a link to download your blender file? This way I will easily see what was my problem and won't do it next time. Also this way I won't be stuck at that part anymore. I have the last version of Blender, 2.9.3

Comment: i added the blend file -> you didn't really take my values in your shader nodes (0.5 instead of 1). I would always exactly copy what you see...you can change the values later on if it works...but at start i would just copy it.